# How to say regrets [I should not have X]

Tags: grammar

How in the world does this:

> 晩ご飯を食べるんじゃなかった。

translate as "I should not have eaten breakfast"?
This roughly translates as "It was not that I eat breakfast."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First and foremost, 「晩{ばん}ご飯{はん}」 means "dinner", and not "breakfast".

Next, let us study the present-tense form of 「～～んじゃなかった」, which will naturally be 「～～んじゃない」.  This might give you a clue.

In ***colloquial*** speech,

> 「Verb or Verb Phrase　+ んじゃ**ない**！」

expresses ***prohibition***.  In other words, this is an informal **negative imperative**.

「ひとりであの公園{こうえん}に行くんじゃない！」= "Don't go to that park alone!"

It is imperative (no pun) that you be familiar with this present-tense usage in order to get a feel for the past tense-usage.

> 「Verb or Verb Phrase + んじゃ**なかった**」

expresses what I might call "retrospective prohibition".  In the plain word, it would be "***regret***".

If the sentence "I should not have eaten dinner." expressed the speaker's regret or repent, then that would be an excellent translation of 「晩ご飯を食べるんじゃなかった」.

> This roughly translate as "It was not that I eat breakfast."

No, it does not, I am afraid.

「食べるんじゃなかった」 surely talks about the past, but the past tense is expressed in the 「なかった」, not in「食べる」.

TL;DR:

> 「食べ**る**んじゃなかった」 = "I should not have eaten."
>
> 「食べ**た**んじゃない/なかった」 = "It was not that I ate." ⇒ "I did something else."

***First sentence says "I ate." and the second, "I didn't eat.", so the difference is huge***.

Once again, be reminded that this is all colloquial speech.　In more formal speech, one would say;

> "I should not have eaten." = 「食べ**る**べきではなかった。」

Comment: Great explanation! Could you please help me by answering this question, I still don't get it, and they are pretty similar questions : http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40861/%e3%81%ae%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8b%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f-vs-%e3%81%ae-%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84-tenses-used

Comment: Are you aware of any reference that mentions these two usages? I have looked through several grammar texts, like the Dictionaries of Japanese Grammar, Tae Kim's Guide, JGram, even the Daijirin... not a single one of them seems to mention these two things. Why is this? It's not that I doubt you, but I find it baffling that something that's supposed to be common is not mentioned in texts.

Comment: As a question (rather than an imperative / exclamation), does「V+ んじゃない?」mean "He does V, doesn't he"?

Answer (score 0):

たべるんじゃない or basically ~んじゃない roughly means that actually.

んじゃない can be used to give suggestions (should have could have). For example if I wanted to tell you that you shouldn't have posted this kind of question on stack overflow

こんな質問、stack overflowでするんじゃなかった

From Maggie-sensei:

> Ex. そうやるんじゃないよ、こうだよ！
>
> = Souyarun janaiyo. Kou dayo!
>
> = Don’t do it that way. Do it this way!
>
> Ex. 風邪ひくからこんなところで寝るんじゃないよ！(tough speech)
>
> = Kaze hikukara konna tokoro de nerun janai yo.
>
> = Don’t sleep here or you will catch cold.