# （来る）んだったなって = should have (come)?

Tags: grammar

しかもこんなオマケまで見られるんなら、ほんと、子供の頃にも遊びに来るんだった**なって**

Furthermore, if i were able to see this kinda of bonus (sunset) , honestly, i (should have?) came here to play when i was a kid.

There is an entry for なう　meaning "to do" as a suffix, but how does it convey the meaning that i think it conveys in this sentence?

should have =  んだったなって  ?

Comment: it's not なう but rather ...だったなと[おもう]. at least that's how i would read this.  where な is the sentence ending particle な.

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41452/9831

Comment: The ん (contraction of の) in 来る**ん**だった is *not* the noun もの "thing", but the particle の.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > しかもこんなオマケまで見られるんなら、ほんと、子供の頃にも遊びに来るんだった**なって**
>
> Furthermore, if i were able to see this kinda of bonus (sunset) ,
>   honestly, i (should have?) came here to play when i was a kid.
>
> should have = んだったなって ?

As A.Ellett says, it's だったなと[おもう].
It's a contraction of 遊びに来るのだったなと（思う）. It's the same as 遊びに来ればよかったなと思う, so you guessed right and it's saying "I should have come to play here when I was a kid."

And we never really say these, but I think this の is representing もの, 'things'.
来るんだったな（＜来るのだったな＜来るものだったな＝来るべきものだったな＝）来ればよかったな

Comment: ah i see thanks, one of the the more cryptic contractions i've come upon

Comment: with something like 正直言えば、だったらいいなって希望だけだ,  is the なって here also と思う/と思って？

Comment: Hi charu, It's basically the same, but this one, unlike the above one, is not the end of the sentence; it has 希望だけだ. So, it would make it more natural if it's rephrased as だといいなという希望だけだ. The above one, 遊びに来るんだったなって, is an example which ended the sentence without saying the verb. I suspect the speaker has said something like "私、思います" right before that sentence.

Comment: is this also the case where " な is the sentence ending particle な" as well?

Comment: Ah... right. な in 来るんだったなって, よかったな, いいなって, whether with or without って, they are all the same particle, 終助詞; the ending pargicle, and in these cases it expresses wishes or feeling of admiration or surprise.

Comment: [correction] pargicle > particle

Comment: A little more on this if you don't mind, for something like 伝統ある祭りは違うなって感じでした/I feel traditional festivals are different, would this be 違うなと感じでした or somehow still a variant of 違うなと思う。。。？　Thanks

Comment: 違うなって感じでした＝違うなという感じでした. We don't say 違うなと感じでした, though we say 違う（な）と感じました, or 違う感じでした. I think it's because な is an ending particle, we feel there's a sentence or clause right before it. Also 感じでした＝名詞＋でした while 感じました is one verb.